# Get result using two tables without using any loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

**I have two tables Temp_Test and Temp_Marks.**

**Temp_Test is having following columns**

```
id  UserId  QId QTitle  QMarks
1     A1     1    A       5
2     A1     2    B       6
3     A1     3    C       4
4     A1     4    D       5
5     B3     1    A       8
6     B3     2    B       6
7     B3     3    C       4
8     B3     4    D       3
9     Z9     1    A       2
10    Z9     2    B       7
11    Z9     3    C       9
12    Z9     4    D       3
```

**and Temp_Marks has following Columns**

```
Id  Score   A     B    C     D
1     1     10    5    40    12
2     2     20    10   50    23
3     3     30    15   60    34
4     4     40    20   70    54
5     5     50    25   80    84
6     6     60    30   90    36
7     7     70    35   10    85
8     8     80    40   20    97
9     9     90    45   30    58
10    10    100   50   100   48
```

**I want to fetch result of particular UserId.**

eg. If for A1, QTitle is A and marks is 5 in Temp_test table then fetch record from Column A where Score is 5 from Temp_Marks table.

without using while loop want to fetch all records of particular UserId or UserIds.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What have you tried? You will learn more if you attempt it yourself.Plus it is far easier for us to correct a minor mistake than invent an answer from nothing.

Comment: Please post the expected result format.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I want result in following format <br/> <br/>


`UserId A B C D  <br/>

A1 50 30 70 84 <br/>

B3 80 30 70 34`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to `UNPIVOT` the `Temp_Marks` first to easily join it with `Temp_Test`, and then `PIVOT` the result to achieve the desired format:

```
;WITH CteUnpivotedMarks AS(
    SELECT
        ID, Score, Col = 'A', Value = A
    FROM Temp_Marks
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID, Score, Col = 'B', Value = B
    FROM Temp_Marks
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID, Score, Col = 'C', Value = C
    FROM Temp_Marks
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID, Score, Col = 'D', Value = D
    FROM Temp_Marks
)
SELECT
    UserId = t.UserID,
    A = MAX(CASE WHEN t.QTitle = 'A' THEN c.Value END),
    B = MAX(CASE WHEN t.QTitle = 'B' THEN c.Value END),
    C = MAX(CASE WHEN t.QTitle = 'C' THEN c.Value END),
    D = MAX(CASE WHEN t.QTitle = 'D' THEN c.Value END)
FROM Temp_Test t
INNER JOIN CteUnpivotedMarks c
    ON t.QTitle = c.Col
    AND t.QMarks = c.Score
GROUP BY t.UserID
```

**RESULT**

```
UserId     A           B           C           D
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
A1         50          30          70          84
B3         80          30          70          34
Z9         20          35          30          34
```

Comment: i have tried query using pivot but without using While loop i'm not able to get an expected result.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Make sure to study this to understand how it works.